# How to remove satellite streaks from photos?

Tags: post-processing, astrophotography, image-stacking, deepskystacker

I found myself struggling a bit removing satellite streaks from my astrophotography. The best option that I found is to use the Healing brush tool in Photoshop, but this has the danger of removing stars as well.

Of course, you could only use the light frames without satellites for stacking, but this may not be an option in some cases.

Which steps can be taken during stacking (I use Deep Sky Stacker and Sequator), postprocessing and possibly shooting to remove satellites preferrably as easy as possible and automatic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sequator should offer a "select best pixels" option that can be used to reduce satellite interference. Otherwise, there is a somewhat [helpful article at Sky&Telescope](https://skyandtelescope.org/astronomy-blogs/imaging-foundations-richard-wright/satellites-begone-how-to-remove-satellite-trails-from-your-astrophotography/) that points to a statistical method called "sigma rejection" or "sigma clipping" that will reject pixels from a stack of images if they change brightness too abruptly.